# How to stop a function on window resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm new with Isotope and in order for some responsive behavior when sizing down the browserwindow I had to add this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if($(window).width() < 800)
    // update columnWidth on window resize
    $(window).smartresize(function(){
        $container.isotope({
            // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
            masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
        });
    });
});
```

It works fine except that when I size it back up the effect doesn't stop. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an event handler firing on `window.resize`, and then you assign another event handler inside it.  You just need the inner one, with the logic of the outer one...

```
$(function() {
    $(window).smartresize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 800) {
            $container.isotope({
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: $container.width() / 5
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```